# git diff release tag and commitID

Tags: git, powershell

I am writing a powershell script that gets me the files changed between release tag and last commit. But the problem I am encountering an issue it doesn't  include the last commit file.  Below are commands.

```
$LatestTag= $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
$ReleaseTag = $(git describe --tags $LatestTag)  
$CommitId =  $(git rev-parse HEAD) 

$files=$(git diff $ReleaseTag..$CommitId~ --name-only)
```

The files includes all changed files except the last committed file.

Comment: Do you have tags defined?

Comment: Is the last commit `CommitId`? If yes, you need to remove the "~". `$CommitId~` means the (first) parent of `$CommitId`

Comment: Yes I do. The plan is to tag master after every release . Since I am testing this I am manually adding tags and commiting code

Comment: As an FYI, those subexpressions are unnecessary: `$()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde in `$CommitId~` means "previous commit". Just remove it to run diff with the last commit:

```
$files=$(git diff $ReleaseTag..$CommitId --name-only)
```